# YouTube Data API v3 Not Found

Tags: api, youtube

I have gone through a tutorial that takes me to the console.developers.google.com/ webpage. I created a new project, then I went to API & Auth .. clicked on the API key to try to then scroll down and select the Youtube Data API v3 and it is NOT there, why? I need to get the API key for an application I am using. I have logged in to two separate accounts and it is not available in either account. I need help in finding the API key so that I can use it in an application.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the console.developers.google.com/ webpage. Open your project. Go to API, scroll down,
use CONTROL + F key to open a search box, type in youtube data V3, you should see it as soon as you start typing.

PS: Command + F on Mac or Control + F on PC